# Just what is Mac Lane & Moerdijk's $\Lambda$ from $\S II.5$?

Tags: category-theory, definition, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

This is a question concerning **Exercise II.6** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Mac%20Lane%20and%20Moerdijk%2C%20%24%5CLambda%24&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

I'm not going to relay all of $\S II.5$ and its references to the $\Lambda$ in question. The definition of $\Lambda$ seems spread across the pages 84 to 87, *ibid.*, bringing together concepts like germs, stalks, and bundles, all of which I have little to no experience of (beyond a brief reading of Goldblatt's, *"Topoi [. . .]"*).

Quoting page 87 of Mac Lane and Moerdijk,

> The left adjoint functor $$\Gamma\Lambda:{\rm Sets}^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{{\rm op}}} \to{\rm Sh}(X)$$ is known as the *associated sheaf functor*, or the *sheafification functor.*

### The Question:

> Just what is the functor $\Lambda$ from $\S II.5$?

### Further Context:

I need to understand $\Lambda$ in order to complete **Exercise II.6**.

I'm reading the book recreationally.

Check my recent questions here to get a rough idea of my abilities.

This is not a question I think I can answer myself.

The kind of answer I'm looking for is, roughly speaking, a detailed description of $\Lambda$ with an eye to the solution of **Exercise II.6**.

Please help :)

Comment: I don't think it is, @DanielSchepler. Perhaps I should edit the question to include more details for those who do not have the book handy.

Comment: I don't think so, @DanielSchepler. Quoting page 87, "The left adjoint functor
$$\Gamma\Lambda:{\rm Sets}^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{{\rm op}}} \to{\rm Sh}(X)$$
is known as the *associated sheaf functor*, or the *sheafification functor.*" Does that help?

Comment: Oh, OK, the sheafification functor is definitely something I'm familiar with.  (Though there are a couple ways to construct it that I'm familiar with: one involves $F^+(U)$ being a subset of $\prod_{x\in U} F_x$, and the other involves $F^+(U)$ being a direct limit over covers of $U$ of an equalizer.  Then there's also a construction involving defining a "closure" operator of subpresheaves and applying that closure operator several times, which generalizes to "sheaves wrt a topology on a topos", but I'm guessing that's not what would be in an earlier chapter.)

Comment: But the functor is defined in the previous pages... You cite pages 84 to 87, but what don't you understand more precisely in these pages? Here is an other explanation: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/007X

Comment: Oh. I've definitely read the preceding material, so I must have forgotten it. Chapter II's exercises are challenging for me and so have taken up a lot of my time - time I'm investing minimally as I've not much of it spare. **Exercise II.6** refers to its $\S 5$, so, naturally, I assumed the definition of $\Lambda$ would be there. What $\Lambda$ does to the arrows of its domain, I suppose, @Idéophage, is my main issue, besides understanding germs properly and the like.

Comment: Thank you for the other explanation, too, @Idéophage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to §5, $\Lambda$ is the functor taking a presheaf $P$ on $X$ and returning the corresponding étale space $\Lambda_P$, which is a topological space with a natural map $p:\Lambda_P\to X$, which is a local homeomorphism.

Explicitly, as a set $\Lambda_P$ is the disjoint union $\coprod_{x\in X}P_x$ of the germs $P_x$ at each point $x\in X$, and the map $p$ just sends all elements in $P_x$ to $x$. As a topological space, well you should read the corresponding section of §5, it is explained rather well I think, but basically it is the topology such that the *continuous* sections $s:U\to \Lambda_P$ of $p$ are exactly the sections of the sheafification of $P$.

Now you say you have "little experience" with germs, but I don't know how you are expecting to solve exercises from a book on sheaves without diving into those notions.

Comment: Thank you, @CaptainLama. I'm trying my best.

Comment: Should that be "étalé space" as opposed to "étale space"?  (Vague memory of a distinction.)

Comment: So, the possibly discontinuous sections of $p$ are exactly $\prod_{x\in X} P_x$ and that relates it to the first construction that I mentioned in the question comments.